# How to filter the data which contains the depth of one using same syntax?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const usersData = [
  {
    
    count: 5,
    providerList: [
      {
        gender: "F",
        languageCodes: [
          {
            code: "JPN",
            desc: "Japan"
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        gender: "F",
        languageCodes: [
          {
            code: "SPN",
            desc: "Spanish"
          },
          {
            code: "IND",
            desc: "Indian"
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        gender: "F",
        languageCodes: [
          {
            code: "IND",
            desc: "Indian"
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        gender: "M",
        languageCodes: [
          {
            code: "US",
            desc: "English"
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        gender: "M",
        languageCodes: [
          {
            code: "Aus",
            desc: "English"
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
];

let key=['gender']
let value=['M']

let finalData = usersData[0].providerList.filter(function(e) {
  return key.every(function(a) {
    return value.includes(e[a]);
  });
});

console.log(finalData)
```

Here the code contains the sample data for the gender and language.when user executes the using key and value is maintained into the snippet you will get the finalData as output.

Here my question is I also want to filter the value of languageCodes means if the key=['code'] value=['Indian'] it will filter the data accordingly.
Here my problem is that I do not want to change the key and value variable into the snippet like 
return key.every(function(a) {return value.includes(e[a]);

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only works if `usersData` has always the same format

```js
var _key=['code']
var _value=['Aus']

function _filter(data, key, value){
  return data.filter(function(a){
    return a[key] == value ||  (a.languageCodes && _filter(a.languageCodes, key, value).length)
  })
}

console.log(_filter(usersData[0].providerList, _key, _value))
```

```html
<script>
const usersData = [{

  count: 5,
  providerList: [{
      gender: "F",
      languageCodes: [{
        code: "JPN",
        desc: "Japan"
      }],
    },
    {
      gender: "F",
      languageCodes: [{
          code: "SPN",
          desc: "Spanish"
        },
        {
          code: "IND",
          desc: "Indian"
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      gender: "F",
      languageCodes: [{
        code: "IND",
        desc: "Indian"
      }],
    },
    {
      gender: "M",
      languageCodes: [{
        code: "US",
        desc: "English"
      }],
    },
    {
      gender: "M",
      languageCodes: [{
        code: "Aus",
        desc: "English"
      }],
    }
  ]
}];
</script>
```